# In Mac OS X Terminal, how can I change the font color of comment lines?

Tags: macos, terminal

I can't figure out how to change the font color for comment lines only (starting with a #), in Terminal.

I find it much clearer when I can easily see which lines are comments and which lines are not.

**EDIT**: I am using Nano and I want to connect to my remote Ubuntu machine via SSH, from Terminal in Mac OS X.

Comment: Are you using a text editor that is syntax highlighting your code?

Comment: I took away the `[linux]` tag. If you can explain how this is a Linux question, we'll be happy to add it back.

Comment: Hi, I just want to use Nano. I am connecting to a Linux machine via SSH, from my personal Mac. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think, it doesn't have anything to do with mac osx or terminal.

You can set up syntax highlighting for nano. See this page, for example: [Syntax highlighting on nano](https://askubuntu.com/q/90013).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. The syntax highlighting seems to be working only when I open nanorc configuration file, but otherwise, any other text file is all in white font. Thanks again

Comment: Do you have syntax highlighting files for other languages? Do you have them loaded in `~/.nanorc`?